# Compiling CUDA code from the command line

Tags: c++, cuda, gpgpu

I am trying to compile CUDA code from the command line, using the syntax:

```
nvcc -c MyFile.cu -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin"
```

I have CUDA Toolkit version 5.5 installed as well as Visual C++ 2010 Express. I do not have a full version of Visual Studio.

I am receiving the following error message:

```
nvcc : fatal error : nvcc cannot find a supported version of Microsoft Visual Studio. Only the versions 2008, 2010, and 2012 are supported
```

I have seen precedent of people getting VC2010 Express compiling with CUDA Toolkit 5.0, e.g., in this thread

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/535527/?comment=3762165

Therefore, I cannot understand what critical difference there would be, just because it's CUDA 5.5 and not 5.0. Would it make a difference that it's VC Express and not VC Professional? Why would that matter where compiling is concerned? Do Pro and Express really use very different compilers?

Comment: @warunapww Why did you add the `visual-studio-2010` tag? The OP explicitly said that he doesn't have a full version of Visual Studio.

Comment: You should pass the path to executable but not to folder there it is located as -ccbin parameter.

Comment: @cuda geek: I don't think that's it. According to the documentation at the following link, a directory is expected for ccbin. However, I tried appending cl.exe with no difference in the result http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/#file-and-path-specifications

Answer (score 4):

I can't post comments yet and I don't know if this is a correct answer since I don't have 2010 express. So in the interest of helping I'll try with an answer.

I can supply you with the start of my compile line, which is slightly different from yours:

```
set CUDAFE_FLAGS=--sdk_dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\"
"C:\_work\API\CUDA\bin\nvcc.exe" --use-local-env --cl-version 2012 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64"        --keep-dir x64\Prod -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64
```

From this I expect you to change the path to yours, and the cl-version as well to

```
"C:\_work\API\CUDA\bin\nvcc.exe" --use-local-env --cl-version 2010 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\cl.exe" --machine 32
```

Please note I have tried to change it to 32-bit as well. I assume this is what you are running.

Cheers

Comment: Hi Henrik. I appreciate your response, but I cannot see how I'd adapt the 'set CUDAFE_FLAGS=...' bit to my platform. I don't have a directory path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\" and don't understand what this is doing well enough to know what the corresponding path would be for me.

Comment: Hi. To be honest I don't know why it is required exactly. Does it work without it? It is most likely a path definition, so if a header or library is missing, you can probably add the include paths directly. I could not find it in the deviceQuery makefile on linux, so it might be something that is specific to the VS custom build.