# Setting CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS using CMake

Tags: c++, cuda, cmake

I am trying to compile a CUDA project using CMake on Windows. I am not familiar with make or CMake and I have done some reading over the past few days, but I am still not able to figure this out. I get the following error message:

```
Chri@Riemann-PC /cygdrive/c/Apps/ThirdParty/MAGMA/magma-2.0.1/build64
$ make
[  1%] Built target lapacktest
[  1%] Building NVCC (Device) object CMakeFiles/magma.dir/magmablas/magma_generated_zherk_batched_core.cu.o
nvcc fatal   : nvcc cannot find a supported version of Microsoft Visual Studio. Only the versions 2010, 2012, and 2013 are supported
CMake Error at magma_generated_zherk_batched_core.cu.o.cmake:207 (message):
  Error generating
  /cygdrive/c/Apps/ThirdParty/MAGMA/magma-2.0.1/build64/CMakeFiles/magma.dir/magmablas/./magma_generated_zherk_batched_core.cu.o


CMakeFiles/magma.dir/build.make:2058: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/magma.dir/magmablas/magma_generated_zherk_batched_core.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/magma.dir/magmablas/magma_generated_zherk_batched_core.cu.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:105: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/magma.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/magma.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

---

Using the make VERBOSE=1 command, I get the following error:

```
cd /cygdrive/c/Apps/ThirdParty/MAGMA/magma-2.0.1/build64/CMakeFiles/magma.dir/magmablas && /usr/bin/cmake.exe -D verbose:BOOL=1 -D build_configuration:STRING= -D generated_file:STRING=/cygdrive/c/Apps/ThirdParty/MAGMA/magma-2.0.1/build64/CMakeFiles/magma.dir/magmablas/./magma_generated_zherk_batched_core.cu.o -D generated_cubin_file:STRING=/cygdrive/c/Apps/ThirdParty/MAGMA/magma-2.0.1/build64/CMakeFiles/magma.dir/magmablas/./magma_generated_zherk_batched_core.cu.o.cubin.txt -P /cygdrive/c/Apps/ThirdParty/MAGMA/magma-2.0.1/build64/CMakeFiles/magma.dir/magmablas/magma_generated_zherk_batched_core.cu.o.cmake
-- Removing /cygdrive/c/Apps/ThirdParty/MAGMA/magma-2.0.1/build64/CMakeFiles/magma.dir/magmablas/./magma_generated_zherk_batched_core.cu.o
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E remove /cygdrive/c/Apps/ThirdParty/MAGMA/magma-2.0.1/build64/CMakeFiles/magma.dir/magmablas/./magma_generated_zherk_batched_core.cu.o
-- Generating dependency file: /cygdrive/c/Apps/ThirdParty/MAGMA/magma-2.0.1/build64/CMakeFiles/magma.dir/magmablas/magma_generated_zherk_batched_core.cu.o.NVCC-depend
"/cygdrive/c/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v7.5/bin/nvcc.exe" -M -D__CUDACC__ /cygdrive/c/Apps/ThirdParty/MAGMA/magma-2.0.1/magmablas/zherk_batched_core.cu -o /cygdrive/c/Apps/ThirdParty/MAGMA/magma-2.0.1/build64/CMakeFiles/magma.dir/magmablas/magma_generated_zherk_batched_core.cu.o.NVCC-depend -ccbin /usr/bin/gcc.exe -m64 -Xcompiler ,\"-fopenmp\",\"-Wall\",\"-Wno-unused-function\",\"-g\" -DHAVE_CUBLAS -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=compute_35 -DNVCC "-I/cygdrive/c/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v7.5/include" "-I/cygdrive/c/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v7.5/include" -I/cygdrive/c/Apps/ThirdParty/MAGMA/magma-2.0.1/include -I/cygdrive/c/Apps/ThirdParty/MAGMA/magma-2.0.1/control
nvcc fatal   : nvcc cannot find a supported version of Microsoft Visual Studio. Only the versions 2010, 2012, and 2013 are supported
```

---

It is still using the gcc compiler (-ccbin /usr/bin/gcc.exe).

I went into the file: `C:\Apps\ThirdParty\cygwin64\usr\share\cmake-3.3.2\Modules\FindCUDA.cmake` and added the following lines:

```
set(VS_DIR "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\bin")
message(${VS_DIR})
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "-ccbin ${VS_DIR}" CACHE STRING "Semi-colon delimit multiple arguments.")
```

I also added the following line to the nvcc.profile file:

```
CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS += -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin";
```

Still no luck. I have spent a few days trying to fix this. I am grateful for any help in this matter.

Comment: Similar question about passing path to VS for nvcc: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760374/why-cant-nvcc-find-my-visual-c-installation. As you already have VS installed, the first answer (by sjchoi) doesn't fit for you. But others should work.

Answer (score 3):

The option to set the host compiler in `FindCUDA` is `CUDA_HOST_COMPILER`, see the [FindCUDA documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindCUDA.html).

Try

```
set(CUDA_HOST_COMPILER "<path to compiler executable>")
```

or alternatively set it when invoking the `cmake` command

```
cmake .. -DCUDA_HOST_COMPILER=<path to compiler executable>
```

I guess the `CUDA_HOST_COMPILER` option overrides the `ccbin` settings of `CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS`. For other options you can use `CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS` in the way you tried. (Thus, the title is misleading. It is not a problem of how to set `CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS`.)

I use this often on Linux, however I don't have a Windows environment to test it there.